# Different structure path of python base program

Tags: python, django, path, filesystems, test-coverage

when i works with coverage i see that when i want to run test with it i must code for example like "coverage run manage.py test src.apps.accounts.tests " in terminal and when i want see the result i must write "coverage report --include=src/apps/service/accounts/* -m " .my question is why we use ". " for run and use "/ " for see the result? and in general when we should use "." and when we should use "/" (this example did not only one case i see so i want a way to understand when should use each other of them)
*in advance i am tank you for get me full solution and read the my question that write with my weak english understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"." is the pythonic way of writing paths, "/" is for general purpose

When you are including apps in your settings.py, you will write it with "."

When you are saving a file on your computer (with notepad or any other software), you will use "/"

Comment: but these two commands from one package call coverage

Comment: Yeah, but the first one calls manage.py, and the second one includes a directory from the file system. The first is calling manage.py, so it's using python notation, the second is looking somewhere in your file system so it needs to use the file system notation.

Comment: It also depends of who wrote the software : not everyone uses the python standards. The pythonic way of writing paths isn't a fixed rule, some people just do things their way.